# Handle csv table in Python without pandas, csv or any other modules or libraries

Tags: python, csv

Using Python, I need to read a csv table.
I need to assign that csv table to a variable so I can handle it later to filter, remove duplicates, etc.

I have restricted conditions like I can not use any module or library, just with native Python functions.

Looking on internet, I only find examples of `pandas` or `csv` modules for working with the csv table.

Is it possible to do some of these tasks in Python without using modules or libraries? *(this is a school activity)*

Comment: Are you sure you have understood the problem description correctly because it seems to me that expecting you to download a URL "without any other libraries" is unrealistic. Beside, `urllib` *is* a native Python function (well, actually a module) so why can't you use this?

Comment: I've just asked again. You were right. They don't expect me to automatically download the information using python. I have to download the file by hand. But I have to handle the csv without using any library or module Now I'll update the question.

Comment: What have you tried until now? @Joracosu

Comment: I've searched on internet things like 'sort csv with Python' or 'remove duplicates with Python' or 'filter rows in csv with python'... but in all cases I found or 'pandas' or 'csv' modules. I need to filter the csv with one condition and retrieve the result of other column.

Comment: Ok... so simple... just `open` command, `split` and a `for` loop… :_( I've spend around 4 hours to get this solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously it depends on what you are looking for but it can be easily done with `open`, `rstrip` and `split`

```
csvtable=open('path\file_name.csv')
separator = ','
ntable=[]

for row in csvtable:
    if (separator in row):
        row=row.rstrip()
        row=row.split(separator)
        ntable += [row]
```